# How does HBase delete a row while it is still in memstore?

Tags: row, hbase

Assume I just added a row to a table and the row is still in the memstore. At this point, I deleted it. What happened for deletion? I am not sure if my understanding is right: A marker is added for that row in the memstore. When the memstore is flushed, the row and the marker are written to HFile. But if that is the case, why isn't the row removed from memstore?

Answer (score 1):

The way HBase works is that every change is a new "insert". This let's hbase work in an efficient manner. You should also keep in mind that in many cases HBase is set to save x versions of each value. So a time where the row is just in the memstore and it should only keep one version of the row is a very specific edge case. It is better for the system to work in a single, predicted and tested way than to handle that edge case.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that that a row with same rowkey already exists in Store file on disk, in which case another add with same rowkey will be an update to the existing row, resulting into a new version of that row. 
Saving the newly added row with delete marker from memstore would allow major compaction to  remove all old versions of that row upto the version with delete marker.